# LogicAPP convert Markdown to HTML

Tags: html, markdown, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to convert markdown to HTML.

In my flow, when an email is sent, the content of a file .md should be sent in an email body as HTML.

I saw a video where using an action "Conver Markdown to HTML (preview) - Cloudmersirve Document Version" could be done, however this action no longer exists, another way to do it?

Thank you community.

I used "When an email is received" as a trigger, for nothing in particular, just to test the flow.
From onedrive I used get content from the file, where I have a .md file whose information I want to reflect in the body of an email.

After this, I sent an email to be able to see the result, marking, inside the body, Is it HTML?, it didn't work. My idea is to be able to reflect the content of that markdown in the body of the email correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the text that’s marked down so we have a chance of helping?

Comment: Hello, actually there is no text, that is, I'm just testing, although I understand that it will be a header and table of the style.

#HEADER
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | text | text |
| text | text | text |

Of course, the idea is see this content like a html not a markdown

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could get this done using automation account. I am using `markdown` module to convert .md content to html content. Below is the process that I followed.

Below is the sample .md content I used

```
- sample1
- sample2
- sample3
```

Here is the flow of my logic app

[image]

[image]

For testing purposes I have sent an email with the received content from automation account.

[image]

Script in Automation Account that worked for me.

```
import sys
import markdown as md

mdfile = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])

# Convert the Markdown to HTML
html_text = md.markdown(mdfile)

print(html_text)
```

#### Results:

Run in Logic app

[image]

Results received in outlook

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'll try it today, I hope to gert lucky :)